Exposing a gradle task in an android AAR
I have an android library distributed as an AAR via maven. For my library to work the app needs to download a file and store it into its assets folder. I have created a task in my library's build.gradle file that does this.
When an application is using my AAR via maven it cannot find the task. What is wrong?
My task:
tasks.register('customDownload', CustomDownloadTask)

class CustomDownloadTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    void doTask() {
        //Do the work
    }
}

In the library project I can do:
./gradlew customDownload

But if I do that in the application project, downloading the AAR via maven it fails with Task 'customDownload' not found in root project...
Can this be accomplished and how?

As your project is a multi-module project, you can't just run the customDownload task as-is, as evident by the error telling you that the task doesn't exist in the root project, so you'll have to prefix the task with the path to the project (e.g. :lib:) for it to work. This is also documented in the command-line usage.

In a multi-project build, subproject tasks can be executed with : separating the subproject name and task name. The following are equivalent when run from the root project:
$ gradle :subproject:taskName

$ gradle subproject:taskName

You can also run a task for all subprojects using a task selector that consists of only the task name.
The following command runs the test task for all subprojects when invoked from the root project directory:
$ gradle test


Assuming your library is located at the library/ folder (which has a build.gradle/build.gradle.kts file):
./gradlew :library:customDownload

If you're using an IDE which shows a tree view of the Gradle tasks that your projects have (e.g. IntelliJ), you can also try manually invoking the Gradle task from there.

As a side-note, you can make Gradle automatically add your custom task as a dependency when publishing your library, see the Controlling Task Execution docs for more information.

Thank you for your reply. Can you confirm that this works when accessing the library via a maven dependecy. I can run the task when in the same project.
Also, in the quote you attached, it says "You can also run a task for all subprojects using a task selector that consists of only the task name." which works as well, when in the same project. I need to distribute the gradle task in the AAR along with the library code.
